# Initialize field with raw pointer to object after base class constructed with moved unique_ptr to same object

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I have an object `Foo` owned by `Owner` and no one else.  I create an object of class `Derived` that inherits `Owner`, passing it a `unique_ptr` to a newly created `Foo`.  `Derived` has a member of class `User` that also needs to use `Foo`, but doesn't own it, so it gets only a raw pointer to it.

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Foo {
  void talk() { cout << "foo" << endl; }
};

struct User {
  Foo *foo;
  User(Foo *_foo): foo(_foo) {};
  void use() { foo->talk(); } //potential disaster if foo's memory has changed
};

struct Owner {
  unique_ptr<Foo> foo;
  Owner(unique_ptr<Foo> _foo): foo(move(_foo)) {};
};

struct Derived : public Owner {
  User user;
  Derived(unique_ptr<Foo> _foo)
  : Owner {move(_foo)},
    user{_foo.get()}  //potential disaster: _foo has already been move()'d, can't get()!
  {};
  void use() { user.use(); };
};

int main() {
  Derived d(make_unique<Foo>());
  //do other stuff
  d.use();  //potential disaster
}
```

The problem is that in the initialization list of `Derived`, I need to `move()` the `Foo` to pass it to `Owner`'s constructor (which takes a `unique_ptr<Foo>`, because it is the owner), and also pass a raw pointer to the `Foo` to `User`.  But by the time the `User` gets initialized, the `unique_ptr<Foo>` has already been moved and `foo.get()` may point to an invalid location!

What's a good way to make sure `User` gets a valid (non-owning) pointer to `Foo` and `Owner` still gets its `unique_ptr<Foo>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could delegate the work to a private constructor while duplicating the pointer:

```
struct Derived : public Owner {
  User user;
  Derived(unique_ptr<Foo> _foo)
  : Derived(move(_foo), _foo.get())
  {};

  void use() { user.use(); };
private:
  // Implement the real logic here
  // As pointed by @Artyer in the comments, this r-value ref is required. 
  // Pass by value would again introduce UB in the calling code.
  Derived(unique_ptr<Foo>&& _foo, Foo* ptr)
   : Owner {move(_foo)},
    user{ptr} {}
};
```

Note, that `Derived(move(_foo),_foo.get())` is safe even though the order of evaluation is unspecified because `std::move` is just a cast.

<s>Just for clarity, this is not a potential disaster but a certain one
since the initializer list is evaluated from left to right.</s>

[9.4.4.4 [dcl.init.list]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#4):

> Within the
> initializer-list of a braced-init-list, the initializer-clauses,
> including any that result from pack expansions ([temp.variadic]), are
> evaluated in the order in which they appear. **That is, every value
> computation and side effect associated with a given initializer-clause
> is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated
> with any initializer-clause that follows it in the comma-separated
> list of the initializer-list.** [Note: This evaluation ordering holds
> regardless of the semantics of the initialization; for example, it
> applies when the elements of the initializer-list are interpreted as
> arguments of a constructor call, even though ordinarily there are no
> sequencing constraints on the arguments of a call. — end note]
> .

### **ADDED: Why does the private constructor require pass by reference**

@Artyer posted the correct explanation with a counter-example but since then has unfortunately deleted it.

There are two reasonable ways to write the delegating constructor:

```cpp
Derived(unique_ptr<Foo>&& _foo, Foo* ptr) //(A)
Derived(unique_ptr<Foo> _foo, Foo* ptr) //(B) Since the move is cheap.
```

And suppose that it was called like this:

```cpp
Derived(move(_foo), _foo.get()) //(1)
Derived{move(_foo), _foo.get()} //(2) @Artyer's idea
```

First, by adding a delegating constructor we essentially added a sequencing point that had to evaluate both the unique and raw pointer before passing them to `Owner` and `User`, respectively.

Second, all the arguments for a function call must be evaluated before the function is actually called, this order is unspecified for `()` and left-to-right for `{}`(see the delete paragraph above).

Here lies the difference, if (B) is used, the copy has to be made at the call place and for `()` this copy can be made before assigning `_foo.get()` to `ptr` argument. For `{}` it will always happen before. Thus setting `ptr` incorrectly.

On the other hand, if (A) is chosen, only the r-value reference is copied into the argument and `ptr` will always get the correct value no matter whether `(1)` or `(2)` is used.

Comment: This is a member initializer not an initializer list. Members will always be initialized after all base constructors are called and then in the order in which they are defined in the class. The order in the member initializer doesn't matter, i.e. both `: Owner {move(_foo)}, user{ptr}` and `: user{ptr}, Owner {move(_foo)}` do the same thing.

Comment: Oh, my bad, of course you right, I confused them for each other.

Comment: @Artyer I edited it to a r-value reference for just that case few minutes ago.

Comment: @Quimby Thank you.  It looks like it should work; However using this method, for some reason I am still getting a segfault when I try to dereference the raw pointer to Foo.  Note that the specific example code above doesn't crash, only my real world code, probably because the memory gets jumbled around more.

However @Timo's answer works (get()'ing the ptr straight from the base class Foo).  For some reason, in your method, ptr still points to something invalid inside the private `Derived()` constructor (I tried to dereference it there and got a segfault).  I wonder why?

Comment: @Naju Does your private constructor take the `unique_ptr` by r-value reference? Passing by value here will not work.

Comment: @Quimby Ah! Indeed it didn't.  Now it works.  I'll accept this solution because although @Timo's is simpler, this one works even if `foo` is private in `Owner`.  Could you explain a little bit why taking the `unique_ptr` by value in the private constructor caused the raw ptr to be invalid?  I can't see @Artyer's comment unfortunately.

Comment: @Quimby Much obliged. To be absolutely sure I understand: Let's say `(2)` is used so the copy is always made before assigning `_foo.get()` to the `ptr` argument. Then if `(B)` is used, the move constructor of `unique_ptr` calls `release()` on _foo, which makes `_foo.get()` (called later) incorrect at the call site.  But if `(A)` is used, then all that happens is a pointer to _foo is passed to the private constructor leaving `_foo.get()` valid at the call site.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Naju Yes, that is indeed correct (2)(B) should always lead to `ptr` being nullptr. To be exact, the "pointer" passed is r-value reference to the temporary created by the first public constructor. This temporary was constructed at the calling site in `main`. The essential thing is that `Derived(move(_foo), _foo.get())` does almost nothing to the `unique_ptr`(only the cast) and it must execute before the private constructor. Thus creating a safe place where the pointers can be split in two. (2) made a hard-to-spot temporary in this place.

Answer (score 5):

You can make the member of your base class protected (or some higher accessibility) and refer to the base member

```
Derived(unique_ptr<Foo> _foo)
  : Owner {move(_foo)},
    user{foo.get()} // refers to Owner::foo
```